# Excel VBA using NETWORKDAYS

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a sub that checks if changes has happened in column `F` and writes the timestamp to a corresponding cell in column `G`. How do i edit this sub to return the network days in column `H` by finding the difference between the timestamp in column H and Cell containing a week commencing date `A1`? Without VBA, the formula is `=ABS(NETWORKDAYS(A1, B1) - SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(A1, H1))`. Below is my code so far. Any help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim r As Range, c As Range
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With Target
    'check if change happened in column F
    If .Column = 6 Then
      'check if changed value is X
      If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        'add datestamp if it is
         Cells(.Row, 7).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
         Cells(.Row, 8).Value = ABS(NETWORKDAYS(G5,H2)-SIGN(NETWORKDAYS(G5,H2)
      Else
        'clear datestamp and Column H if not
        Cells(.Row, 7).Value = ""
        Cells(.Row, 8).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

'

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim r As Range, c As Range
  Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, wf As WorksheetFunction
  Dim N As Long

  Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With Target
    'check if change happened in column F
    If .Column = 2 Then
      'check if changed value is X
      If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        'add datestamp if it is
        d1 = Cells.Range("A1")
        d2 = Cells.Range("B1:B2")
        N = wf.NetworkDays(d1, d2)
        Cells(.Row, 4).Value = N

      Else
        'clear datestamp and Colunm H if not
        Cells(.Row, 4).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you getting?  Your source code doesn't have matching closing parentheses in the NETWORKDAYS line.

Comment: The datestamp works as expected but the network day part does not

Comment: I edited indents except the extra `End Sub` that you should check. It is impossible that you see two `Sub` with thee `End Sub` on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use *Networkdays()* in **VBA**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim N As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    d1 = DateValue("1/1/2014")
    d2 = DateValue("12/31/2014")
    N = wf.NetworkDays(d1, d2)
    MsgBox N
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I cleaned up your indentations it's pretty clear that you have an "End Sub" in the middle of an "If" statement in your "Worksheet_Change" sub.  Formatting helps you catch this kind of thing.